# Oralce: How to ensure Oracle function is executed serially

Tags: oracle, concurrency, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle database version - 12.1.0.2.0

I've an Oracle function that I need to ensure is executed serially. I want to restrict concurrent execution of this function by different sessions.

Couple of ways this can be achieved is:

1. Update a "static" row in a parameter table at beginning of function and commit before function ends. Since no other session will be able to update same row, it will ensure concurrent access is restricted.
2. Implement logic using user locks.

Is there any other way this control can be achieved. I've read about "latch", but I believe it is used for internal mechanism to control access to Oracle data structures (mainly resource in SGA).
Is there a way to implement latch (or something similar) to fulfill my requirement.

I understand latch is lightweight as against locks which are heavier in comparison.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what the function does ? can you provide what the concurrence needs to handle ? are you making DML inside the function or only select ?

Comment: To put it in simplistic terms, I'm looking for a combination of 3 fields in a table, 2 of which are unique and 3rd is sequence number. If combination exists for 2 fields, then I want to use it further for processing. If it does not exist then create one by attaching a sequence number. Since there multiple process running concurrently, it is possible that 2 process find that combination doesn't exist and both go on to create that combination resulting in "sort of" duplicates. If I make the function execute serially, then this scenario of duplicates won't happen.

Comment: You should check if you do not want to implement a *messaging system*, i.e. you have several executors, but each request in enqueued only once. This would point to DBMS_AQ. Otherwise check the ALLOCATE_UNIQUE from the answer below, where you will use your two field as a lockname. But my feeling is that would be a sort of *overkill*.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle implementes   [DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE_UNIQU](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_LOCK.html#GUID-73F03FA6-04B3-4341-AB4F-8BECCF898D13)E for this purpose.

At the beginning of the procedure allocate a unique lockhandle for a given lockname.
Then REQUEST the lock

```
 /* lock parallel executions */
DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE_UNIQUE( v_lockname, v_lockhandle);
v_res := DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST( lockhandle=>v_lockhandle, release_on_commit => TRUE);
```

Perform your serial stuff  and at the end of the function   RELEASE the lock.

```
v_res :=  DBMS_LOCK.RELEASE (v_lockhandle);
```

Do not forget to release the lock in the EXCEPTION section to be not  blocked after abnormal termination

Comment: Thanks. This is what I referred to with 2nd point - implement logic with user locks.